# Compiler complaining about standard template library - "error: expected template-name before '<' token"

Tags: c++, vector, stl

I'm using TDM-GCC-64 to compile my project through JetBrains CLion, but whenever I go to compile the code, I get the error

```
C:/TDM-GCC-64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/include/c++/bits/stl_bvector.h:137:25: error: expected template-name before '<' token : public std::iterator<std::random_access_iterator_tag, bool>
```

which seems to be telling me that there is an error in stl_bvector.h. Is this a problem with the compiler's implementation of the stl, or is there something that I'm missing? I can't seem to find anything relevant in StackOverflow or anywhere else - all the results are about people attempting to write their own iterators, and the answers don't seem to help me at all.

My relevant code follows
***DataStream.h***

```
#include <bits/stl_bvector.h>
#include "Binary.h"
#include "Datum.h"

using std::size_t;

/*
Allows for the insertion of data into a compatible object.
*/
class DataStream
{
    friend class Datum;
    friend class Data;

    unsigned char* data = nullptr;
    size_t length = 1;
    bool firstAvailable = true;
    Binary* link = nullptr;

public:
    DataStream();
    explicit DataStream(Binary *);
    DataStream(DataStream const&);
    ~DataStream();

    DataStream& operator<<(bool);
    DataStream& operator<<(char);
    DataStream& operator<<(const char*);
    DataStream& operator<<(wchar_t);
    DataStream& operator<<(unsigned char);
    DataStream& operator<<(short int);
    DataStream& operator<<(unsigned short int);
    DataStream& operator<<(int);
    DataStream& operator<<(long int);
    DataStream& operator<<(long long int);
    DataStream& operator<<(unsigned int);
    DataStream& operator<<(unsigned long int);
    DataStream& operator<<(unsigned long long int);
    DataStream& operator<<(float);
    DataStream& operator<<(double);
    DataStream& operator<<(long double);
    DataStream& operator<<(Datum);

    DataStream& operator<<(std::vector<bool>);
    DataStream& operator<<(std::vector<char>);
    DataStream& operator<<(std::vector<wchar_t>);
    DataStream& operator<<(std::vector<unsigned char>);
    DataStream& operator<<(std::vector<short int>);
    DataStream& operator<<(std::vector<unsigned short int>);
    DataStream& operator<<(std::vector<int>);
    DataStream& operator<<(std::vector<long int>);
    DataStream& operator<<(std::vector<long long int>);
    DataStream& operator<<(std::vector<unsigned int>);
    DataStream& operator<<(std::vector<unsigned long int>);
    DataStream& operator<<(std::vector<unsigned long long int>);
    DataStream& operator<<(std::vector<float>);
    DataStream& operator<<(std::vector<double>);
    DataStream& operator<<(std::vector<long double>);
    //DataStream& operator<<(std::vector<Datum>); //<-- I assumed the problem originated here, since it's the only time I use a vector with a class I wrote. However, since commenting it out, nothing has changed.

    void attach(Binary *);

private:
    void changeLength(size_t);

    template <class StreamType>
    DataStream& stdStreamIn(StreamType x) {
        size_t plen;
        if (firstAvailable) {
            if (sizeof(x) - 1 > 1) changeLength(sizeof(x));
            plen = length - 1;
            firstAvailable = false;
        } else {
            plen = length;
            changeLength(length + sizeof(x));
        }
        unsigned char* carr = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(&x);
        auto c = new unsigned char[sizeof(x)];
        for (size_t i = 0, ii = sizeof(x); i < ii; i++)
        {
            c[ii - i - 1] = carr[i];
        }
        for (size_t i = 0, ii = sizeof(x); i < ii; i++)
        {
            data[plen + i] = c[i];
            if (link) link->receive(c[i]);
        }
        return *this;
    }

    template <class StreamType>
    DataStream& realStreamIn(StreamType x) {
        auto plen = length;
        if (firstAvailable) {
            if (sizeof(x) - 1 > 1) changeLength(sizeof(x));
        } else {
            changeLength(length + sizeof(x));
        }
        unsigned char* c = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(&x);
        for (size_t i = 0, ii = sizeof(x); i < ii; i++)
        {
            data[plen + i] = c[sizeof(x) - i - 1];
            if (link) link->receive(c[sizeof(x) - i - 1]);
        }
        return *this;
    }

    template <class Array, class StreamType>
    DataStream& stdArrStreamIn(Array x, std::size_t len) {
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        {
            stdStreamIn<StreamType>(x[i]);
        }
        return *this;
    }

    template <class Array, class StreamType>
    DataStream& realArrStreamIn(Array x, size_t len) {
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        {
            realStreamIn<StreamType>(x[i]);
        }
        return *this;
    }
};
```

***DataStream.cpp***

```
#include "DataStream.h"
#include <string.h>

DataStream::DataStream() {
    data = new unsigned char[1];
}

DataStream::DataStream(Binary *datum) {
    data = new unsigned char[1];
    link = datum;
}

DataStream::DataStream(DataStream const &ds) {
    this->data = new unsigned char[ds.length];
    if (ds.length > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < ds.length; ++i) {
            this->data[i] = ds.data[i];
        }
    }
    if (ds.link) this->link = ds.link;
}

DataStream::~DataStream() {
    if (data) delete[] data;
}

DataStream &DataStream::operator<<(bool x) {
    return stdStreamIn(x);
}

DataStream &DataStream::operator<<(char x) {
    return stdStreamIn(x);
}

DataStream &DataStream::operator<<(const char *x) {
    return stdArrStreamIn<const char *, char>(x, strlen(x));
}

DataStream &DataStream::operator<<(wchar_t x) {
    return stdStreamIn(x);
}

DataStream &DataStream::operator<<(unsigned char x) {
    return stdStreamIn(x);
}

DataStream &DataStream::operator<<(short int x) {
    return stdStreamIn(x);
}

DataStream &DataStream::operator<<(unsigned short int x) {
    return stdStreamIn(x);
}

DataStream &DataStream::operator<<(int x) {
    return stdStreamIn(x);
}

DataStream &DataStream::operator<<(long int x) {
    return stdStreamIn(x);
}

DataStream &DataStream::operator<<(long long int x) {
    return stdStreamIn(x);
}

DataStream &DataStream::operator<<(unsigned int x) {
    return stdStreamIn(x);
}

DataStream &DataStream::operator<<(unsigned long int x) {
    return stdStreamIn(x);
}

DataStream &DataStream::operator<<(unsigned long long int x) {
    return stdStreamIn(x);
}

DataStream &DataStream::operator<<(float x) {
    return realStreamIn(x);
}

DataStream &DataStream::operator<<(double x) {
    return realStreamIn(x);
}

DataStream &DataStream::operator<<(long double x) {
    return realStreamIn(x);
}

DataStream &DataStream::operator<<(Datum x) {
    std::vector<unsigned char> vec;
    for (size_t i = 0, ii = x.size(); i < ii; i++) {
        vec.push_back(x.getByte(i).raw());
    }
    return stdArrStreamIn<std::vector<unsigned char>, unsigned char>(vec, vec.size());
}

DataStream &DataStream::operator<<(std::vector<bool> x) {
    return stdArrStreamIn<std::vector<bool>, bool>(x, x.size());
}

DataStream &DataStream::operator<<(std::vector<char> x) {
    return stdArrStreamIn<std::vector<char>, char>(x, x.size());
}

DataStream &DataStream::operator<<(std::vector<wchar_t> x) {
    return stdArrStreamIn<std::vector<wchar_t>, wchar_t>(x, x.size());
}

DataStream &DataStream::operator<<(std::vector<unsigned char> x) {
    return stdArrStreamIn<std::vector<unsigned char>, unsigned char>(x, x.size());
}

DataStream &DataStream::operator<<(std::vector<short int> x) {
    return stdArrStreamIn<std::vector<short int>, short int>(x, x.size());
}

DataStream &DataStream::operator<<(std::vector<unsigned short int> x) {
    return stdArrStreamIn<std::vector<unsigned short int>, unsigned short int>(x, x.size());
}

DataStream &DataStream::operator<<(std::vector<int> x) {
    return stdArrStreamIn<std::vector<int>, int>(x, x.size());
}

DataStream &DataStream::operator<<(std::vector<long int> x) {
    return stdArrStreamIn<std::vector<long int>, long int>(x, x.size());
}

DataStream &DataStream::operator<<(std::vector<long long int> x) {
    return stdArrStreamIn<std::vector<long long int>, long long int>(x, x.size());
}

DataStream &DataStream::operator<<(std::vector<unsigned int> x) {
    return stdArrStreamIn<std::vector<unsigned int>, unsigned int>(x, x.size());
}

DataStream &DataStream::operator<<(std::vector<unsigned long int> x) {
    return stdArrStreamIn<std::vector<unsigned long int>, unsigned long int>(x, x.size());
}

DataStream &DataStream::operator<<(std::vector<unsigned long long int> x) {
    return stdArrStreamIn<std::vector<unsigned long long int>, unsigned long long int>(x, x.size());
}

DataStream &DataStream::operator<<(std::vector<float> x) {
    return realArrStreamIn<std::vector<float>, float>(x, x.size());
}

DataStream &DataStream::operator<<(std::vector<double> x) {
    return realArrStreamIn<std::vector<double>, double>(x, x.size());
}

DataStream &DataStream::operator<<(std::vector<long double> x) {
    return realArrStreamIn<std::vector<long double>, long double>(x, x.size());
}

//DataStream &DataStream::operator<<(std::vector<Datum> x) {
//    std::vector<unsigned char> vec;
//    for (size_t i = 0, ii = x.size(); i < ii; i++) {
//        for (unsigned int j = 0, jj = x[i].size(); j < jj; j++) {
//            vec.push_back(x[i].getByte(j).raw());
//        }
//    }
//    return stdArrStreamIn<std::vector<unsigned char>, unsigned char>(vec, vec.size());
//}

void DataStream::changeLength(size_t newLength) {
    auto tmp = new char[length];
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        tmp[i] = data[i];
    }
    delete[] data;
    data = new unsigned char[newLength];

    if (newLength >= length) {
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            data[i] = tmp[i];
        }
    }
    else {
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < newLength; i++) {
            data[i] = tmp[i];
        }
    }
    delete[] tmp;
    length = newLength;
}

void DataStream::attach(Binary *data) {
    link = data;
}
```

I apologise for the large slabs of code, but I don't honestly have any idea where the problem originates, only that it's a part of one of those files, based on what the compiler told me.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why are you including `#include <bits/stl_bvector.h>`? You're not supposed to include that sort of header directly.

Comment: `#include <vector>`. Not anything in `bits/`. It's even less typing.

Comment: @Mat Really? When I use Visual Studio I use <vector>, but CLion's automatic-fix functionality includes <bits/std_vector.h>. Should I make sure I use <vector> instead?

Comment: If CLion does that, file a bug. Nothing in `bits/` is meant to be included directly.

Comment: Yep, that fixed the error. Thanks. I can understand why CLion does this - it's algorithm will look for header files that declare the class you're using, which is normally from your own project. I assume that, in this case, it's search found `bits/stl_bvector.h` before `vector`. Thanks again.

Comment: That seems like a crazy thing for a C++ IDE to do. I'd file a bug.

Comment: I guess it's OK to include `<bits/stdc++.h>` if not considering portability.

Comment: @TartanLlama In all fairness to the IDE, it only suggests that header, based on the behaviour I mentioned above, when I hit the quick-fix key command - It's me that didn't know that it causes problems. I will file a bug though, thanks.